# Does Tapestry 5 Have composite components

Tags: java, tapestry

I'm trying to write a composite component like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<t:container xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_0_0.xsd" xmlns:p="tapestry:parameter">
    <t:select t:id="yearField" t:value="year" t:blankOption="always" t:model="yearModel" class="select"/>
    <t:select t:id="monthField" t:value="month" t:blankOption="always" t:model="monthModel" class="select"/>
</t:container>
```

So that I can use it like this

```
<t:dateselector t:value="testDate"></t:dateselector>
```

But I can't find exactly which method to use to get the individual elements and construct the date element. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to add a `value` [parameter](http://tapestry.apache.org/component-parameters.html) of type `Date` and getters and setters for the `year` and `month`properties in your [component class](http://tapestry.apache.org/component-classes.html):

```
public class MyDatePicker {
   @Parameter
   private Date value;

   public Integer getYear() { ... }
   public void setYear(Integer year) { ... }
   public Integer getMonth() { ...}
   public void setMonth(Integer month) { ... }

}
```

You could use Java's [Calendar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) or the vastly superior [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) to get/set the different parts of your date value.

Comment: Form control components are a bit more complicated than other types of components ... you do have to be aware of initial render vs. the eventual form submit. For example, you may want to handle the case where the value parameter is null on a submit. The http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/SubmitNotifier.html component can help there.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did it exactly as you suggested and it worked perfect